# Magento 2 : Add Duplicate of Block or Button Somewhere Else

Tags: magento2, blocks, xml, quote

I have an extension for quote in my store, which displays a **request a quote** button in the cart, when there is content in it.

I want the exact same Button at the **top** in my **menu bar**.

Tried to copy the block call from extensions xml and put it in the `default.xml` from my **custom theme** with reference container header.panel

> This works but is broken(js not working).

Also I would need to check if there is content in cart before.

Im kinda new to this. Would appreciate a hint in the right direction on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe post the content of the xml file where the button  is added initialy. Is the js added inside that xml to the head? Check if the js file thats "broken" is loaded at any other page (via developer tools).